# Is there any other method for exporting data from Microsoft Application Insight other than 'Continuous Export'?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is there any other method for exporting data from Microsoft Application Insight other than 'Continuous Export' ? 
Any server side API for Application Insight for our resource on Azure that can be consumed.

Comment: as far as i 'm aware, this isn't possible yet. depending on the need you can however export into  datasert in PowerBI (even in the free SKU if not mistaken) or use stream analytics and export it into let's say SQL server. No API yet available for exporting as for now  however there's the capabilities through the metrics explorer which allows you to export to Excel or Powerbi to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-metrics-explorer/#export-to-excel

Comment: @techmike2kx but to export data to power BI you have to create a storage container in azure and then fill in the data with continuous export, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Continuous Export is the only supported way at this time. Please continue checking [Application Insights blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/tag/application-insights/) from time to time for new feature announcements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure app service & using any logging then,

First, go to [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) then go inside your specific app service which logs you want to export continuously.

Then see the menu, there you find "Diagnostics logs", go inside the "Diagnostics logs".

Here you find "Application Logging (Blob)", make it on (by default it's off) and add your storage at storage settings.

Here you also find log level and Retention Period. Change it with your convenient value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use API to export the data from Azure Application Insights. https://dev.applicationinsights.io/

There are some limitation:
https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/Rate-limits
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits

To overcome the limitation,I wrote a python script to export the data by limiting the data.
https://gist.github.com/satheeshpayoda/92065d9fbaf5b0158728a8537d79af0e